# Using search in Chef cookbook

Tags: chef-infra

I'm trying to use the search method within a Chef cookbook to retrieve the IP address attribute from a remote node, the IP address will then be used to configure the DNS server settings on the local node.

In my testing I have a domain controller "DC1" and I want to spin up another server from scratch. Before the new server can join to my test domain, it needs to have the correct DNS entry.

As the lab environment, I'm creating is to be spun up and torn down in AWS the IP address for the DNS server will not always be the same.

I would like to be able to get the IP address and store it in a variable for use in the cookbook.

The code snippet I'm trying to use is

```
search(:node, 'name:dc1',
  :filter_result => { 'ip' => [ 'ipaddress' ] }
      ).each do |result|
        ipaddr = result['ip']
end
```

I have tried using the code in attributes/default.rb, but I get an error that search isn't a valid method. Additionally, I have tried my_var = search .... but that didn't work either.

Comment: I am not sure what do you expect from this code. It is assigning proper IP to the local `ipaddr` variable. tensibai helped you with this on community slack. If you want to have it visible outside the block assign it to a variable declared before the search or to node attribute.

Comment: The answer in Slack didn't help with what I'm trying to do. The reason for moving this to Stack Overflow is that it's easy for the issue to get buried in slack. <br> If I use default['network']['ip'] = search ... in attributes or my_var = search... in a recipe I get the error "undefined method `search' for #<Chef::Node::Attribute:0x00000006b5b250>
Did you mean?  each"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After putting the variable in front and removing everything after the filter I stopped getting the error "unidentified method 'search'".

The code that seems to be working is

```
ipaddr = search(:node, 'name:dc1')

dnsserver = ipaddr[0]['ipaddress']
```

I should now be able to use dnsserver in the recipe to set dns servers.